# Get Uri of my Image bitmap in imageview container

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

I have processed an image in activity1 and set that image in activity2 imageview widget. In this activity2 I have a send button to mail this image. I want to send this image as an email attachment. For that I need Uri of the imageview residing in my activity2. How to get the Uri of that imageview as imageview doesnt have getImageUri method.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, you cannot get the URI of the Image until you upload it to the server.
Another option is to add the Image as an ATTACHMENT with the mail.

Comment: True saeed... I want to send it with         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri); where I am going to put the imageview uri over there. Is it the right way?

Comment: Yup... The image that you got from activity 1 must reside somewhere i.e. either in SD card or over the net, you can use that URI as well

Comment: It doesnt resides anywhere I am generating the image by a method according to app requirement.